# mark a checkbox when i choose a value in a select

Tags: angularjs, json, ui-select

Im consuming a JSON file and  i put the values in a select multiple and im trying to mark a checkbox when i select a value in the select but i dont know how can i do that

this is my JSON file

```
 "tipocasa": [
        {"tipo":"Propia" , "tipo_casa":1},
        {"tipo":"Rentada" , "tipo_casa":2},
        {"tipo":"Otro" , "tipo_casa":3}
    ]
```

this is the select code i'm using ui-select

```
          <ui-select multiple ng-model="entrevistainicialModel.idcomportamiento"
                           ng-disabled="false"
                           search-enabled="true"
                           append-to-body="true"
                           class="form-control ">
                    <ui-select-match placeholder="Comportamientos">
                        {{$item.comportamiento}}
                    </ui-select-match>
                    <ui-select-choices repeat="multipleItem.idcomportamiento as multipleItem in datosJson[0].comportamientos | filter: $select.search">
                        {{multipleItem.comportamiento}}
                    </ui-select-choices>
                </ui-select>
```

and this is the checkbox code

```
         <label class="checkbox-inline custom-checkbox nowrap">
            <input align="center" type="checkbox" ng-model="entrevistainicialModel.idcomportamiento" value="1">
                            <span align="center">Propia</span>
                        </label>

             <label class="checkbox-inline custom-checkbox nowrap">
            <input align="center" type="checkbox" ng-model="entrevistainicialModel.idcomportamiento" value="1">
                            <span align="center">rentada</span>
                        </label>

         <label class="checkbox-inline custom-checkbox nowrap">
            <input align="center" type="checkbox" ng-model="entrevistainicialModel.idcomportamiento" value="1">
                            <span align="center">Otro</span>
                        </label>
```

Any idea or suggestion?

Comment: Where is the checkbox, that you suppose to see checked?

Comment: i already modified the post. Sorry

Comment: are multiple checkbox ?? or only one because you are using a multiple select, and the model you asign, is the same as checkbox.

Comment: its a diferent checkbox one for each option. But i put the same model because, i dont know how can i mark the checkbox when i select the value that i need. This checkbox it's just an example. The cuestion is how can i modify the checkbox code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First need to add the `on-remove` and `on-select` to change the models.
And asign. that to each checkbox according your needs.

I made an example based on your data.

**HTML**

```
    <ui-select multiple ng-model="data.selected" on-remove="$item.selected=false" on-select="$item.selected = true" theme="bootstrap" sortable="true" close-on-select="false" style="width: 800px;">
    <ui-select-match placeholder="Comportamientos...">{{$item.name}}</ui-select-match>
    <ui-select-choices repeat="comportamiento in datosJson.comportamientos">
  {{comportamiento.name}}
    </ui-select-choices>
  </ui-select>              
  <p>Selected: {{data.selected}}</p>

  <div ng-repeat="item in datosJson.comportamientos">
    <input type="checkbox" ng-model="item.selected">{{item.name}}
    <br>
  </div>
```

**CONTROLLER**

```
$scope.datosJson = {
comportamientos:
  [
    {id:1, name:'comportamiento1'},
    {id:2, name:'comportamiento2'},
    {id:3, name:'comportamiento3'}
  ]
  };
```

and here is the plnkr with the [DEMO](https://embed.plnkr.co/8hRNf6EzpuVHElzMYcdL/)
Just change your data.

Comment: Gracias por la ayuda funciono!

Comment: glad to help, if this satisfy plz mark like correct. see ya around.